# Can all divisor classes on a one-sheeted hyperboloid be defined over a real extension of the rationals?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

More precisely, let $X$ be a one-sheeted hyperboloid and $Y$ a sphere in $\mathbb{CP}^3$, both defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Can every divisor class on $X$ be defined over some real extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, and can every divisor class on $Y$ be defined over some imaginary quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?

I am trying to understand the phenomenon in which varieties can be isomorphic over certain fields, but not over smaller ones. In this case, it's clear that $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic as varieties over $\mathbb{C}$, as for example the map $[x:y:z]\mapsto [x:y:iz]$ is an isomorphism from $X$ to $Y$.

Now if I can show that the divisor classes of $X$ and $Y$ have the properties described above, then this should suffice to show that they are not isomorphic as varieties over $\mathbb{Q}$.

A quick secondary question: is there a name for the smallest extension of the field of definition of a variety such that every divisor class is defined over that extension? Perhaps the "splitting field of a variety" or something like this?

Comment: Have you looked at simpler examples? This phenomenon first appears in dimension $1$; for instance, if $d > 0$ then the conic $X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 = -d$ has no rational point over $\mathbb R$ (hence the usual "project onto a line" argument that conics are isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$ doesn't work), but of course it is rational over $\mathbb C$. And of course there isn't anything transcendental actually going on; the same thing happens after extending from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-d}]$.

Comment: ...I would assume that non-existence of certain divisor classes similarly obstructs the usual arguments that all smooth quadric surfaces are rational, and I would also guess that by small variations of the argument one can show that the sphere (but not the hyperboloid) is rational, which is actually stronger than what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I'm certainly aware of simpler instances than the one I mentioned, but perhaps I was overzealous. I shall study the usual proofs of rationality of smooth quadrics.